# solr not showing all indexed documents - DataImport

Tags: solr

I am importing records from mysql to SolrCloud 5.2. MySQL contains 487 records. Solr is showing it's imported 487 records.Debug log also shows it's importing the same. However when I query with `*:*`, I am seeing only 233 records. Autocommit is on.

Debug:

```
  "statusMessages": {
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "1",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "487",
    "Total Documents Processed": "487",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2015-07-09 16:29:52",
    "": "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 487 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
    "Committed": "2015-07-09 16:29:54",
    "Time taken": "0:0:2.170"
  }

 "document#485",
      [
        null,
        "----------- row #1-------------",
        "id",
        1000113,
        "name",
        "foldernew1",
        "parentFolderId",
        5,
        "createdDate",
        "2015-04-28T10:11:50Z",
        null,
        "---------------------------------------------"
      ],
```

It is clearly saying id - 1000113 is indexed. But when I query `*:*`, this is not listing.

Comment: You need to give some more information. Have you run a commit command after the import? What version of solr ? What is your solr setup - are u using solr cloud or stand alone? If solr cloud then how many shards? Can you paste the query you are using to fetch?

Comment: Are you seeing duplicate ids for the uniqueKey field, where latter documents ends up overwriting newer ones? What is the current document and max document count in the admin interface?

Comment: Got fixed that issue. I was using the schemaless schema. When I used the  standard schema it started working.